# SwiftUI and Unity integration window hierarchy

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to make an Unity player integration inside a native SwiftUI app. The player should appear when taping a button then user can close the player from Unity and get back to the SwiftUI app.

For the moment I can manage to display the Unity player with this code

### SwiftUI View from where I want to display the player

```swift
//Some SwiftUI View
NavigationView {
 SomeView()
   .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $applicationState.unityPlayerActive, onDismiss: {}, content: {
     //This is a UIViewControllerRepresentable that call the unity.show() function from Unity Framework
      UnityPlayer()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
   })
}
```

### UnityPlayer.swift

```swift
struct UnityPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context _: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        let unity = UnityBridge.getInstance()
        
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            unity.show()
        }
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_: UIViewController, context _: Context) {
      // Empty.
    }
}
```

### UnityBridge.swift

```swift
...
    /// Notifies the UnityFramework to show the window, and append the Unity view
    /// to the given controller
    ///
    /// - Parameter controller: Controller that will host the Unity view
    public func show() {
        ufw.showUnityWindow()
    }

    /// Triggered by Unity via `UnityFrameworkListener` when the framework unloaded
    internal func unityDidUnload(_: Notification!) {
        ufw.unregisterFrameworkListener(self)
        UnityBridge.instance = nil
        
        self.view?.removeFromSuperview()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(closeUnityPlayerNotification), object: nil)
    }
...
```

This code works but when the player is closed the app become unresponsive, the player is still in foreground capturing user's inputs.

I don't have any error message.

Thanks for your help :)

For reference [I have followed the work of David Peicho that explain well the basic logic](https://davidpeicho.github.io/blog/unity-swiftui-integration-revisited/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I commented few lines in `UnityAppController.mm`:

```
//#if (PLATFORM_IOS && defined(__IPHONE_13_0)) || (PLATFORM_TVOS && defined(__TVOS_13_0))
//    if (@available(iOS 13, tvOS 13, *))
//        _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithWindowScene: [self pickStartupWindowScene: application.connectedScenes]];
//    else
//#endif
```

Thus Unity doesn't touch a SwiftUI scene anymore.

In this case, no need to show Unity's window. Instead, it requires directly adding the view controller as a child of another view controller:

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    if let unityVC = UnityFramework.getInstance().appController().rootViewController {
        let view = viewController.view!
        unityVC.willMove(toParent: viewController)
        view.addSubview(unityVC.view)
        unityVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        unityVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        unityVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        unityVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        unityVC.didMove(toParent: viewController)
    }
    return viewController
}
```

In a real application, I used a wrapper view controller for the Unity VC.